# Jenkins not finding Xcode 6 scheme, even though it has been shared

Tags: jenkins, xcode6

I have Jenkins set up to run a build job on a local machine. 
I'm running Xcode 6 and Jenkins 1.598.

This is the console output:

```
Started by user anonymous
....

===========================================================
== Available provisioning profiles
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/security find-identity -p codesigning -v
     0 valid identities found
== Available SDKs
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -showsdks
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.9                       -sdk macosx10.9
    OS X 10.10                      -sdk macosx10.10

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 8.1                         -sdk iphoneos8.1

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 8.1             -sdk iphonesimulator8.1

== Available schemes
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
Information about project "ToDoList":
    Targets:
        ToDoList
        ToDoListTests

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

    **This project contains no schemes.**
===========================================================
Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: ALL, sdk: DEFAULT, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Debug, clean: YES, archive:NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: DEFAULT, codeSignIdentity: DEFAULT
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration Debug clean build
=== CLEAN TARGET ToDoList OF PROJECT ToDoList WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/laura.nakano/.jenkins/jobs/ToDoList_1_DevBuild/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.app

Clean.Remove clean build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.app.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/laura.nakano/.jenkins/jobs/ToDoList_1_DevBuild/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.app.dSYM

Clean.Remove clean build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.app
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/laura.nakano/.jenkins/jobs/ToDoList_1_DevBuild/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.app

Clean.Remove clean build/ToDoList.build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/laura.nakano/.jenkins/jobs/ToDoList_1_DevBuild/workspace/build/ToDoList.build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoList.build

=== CLEAN TARGET ToDoListTests OF PROJECT ToDoList WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/laura.nakano/.jenkins/jobs/ToDoList_1_DevBuild/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/ToDoListTests.xctest

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET ToDoList OF PROJECT ToDoList WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I've set the Scheme in Xcode to be shared and committed.

I only want to run the application on simulator not device, so I don't think I should need to set up code signing.

Has anyone seen a similar issue? I realise my set up is not common.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I have the same error message. Did you post this question somewhere else?